# using twice a $_POST variable in php

Tags: php, mysql, post

Trying to add some values into the table `$_POST["arduinotable"]` depending if they exist or not in `$arduinotableS`. The main problem is that I can get the value  `$valor` two times. When I echo the 1st time it displays correctly, but the 2nd time that I echo the value of same variable it is empty. Here is my code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
if (isset($_POST["arduinotable"]) && isset($_POST["valor"]) ){
    $arduinotable = $_POST["arduinotable"];
    $valor = $_POST["valor"];
    require("config.php");
    $con = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
     echo "1st echo" . $valor;


    //Lets change the value of valor
    $arduinotableS=$arduinotable . "S";
    $sql ="SELECT valor FROM $arduinotableS WHERE ID='$valor'" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);    
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if (empty($result)){
        echo "2nd echo" .  $valor;
       // Esta es la instrucción para insertar los valores
        $query = "INSERT INTO $arduinotable (valor) VALUES('".$_SESSION['valor']."')";
       // Ejecutamos la instrucción
        mysqli_query($con, $query);
       }
    else {
         $value=$row['valor'];
         $query = "INSERT INTO $arduinotable (valor) VALUES('".$value."')";
         mysqli_query($con, $query);
          echo $value;}
}
```

Do you guys know which is the problem? To provide further information, when I enter to the else, the file is able to echo correctly the `$value`...

Thanks!

Comment: you mean `echo "2nd echo" .  $valor;` brings wrong value?

Comment: Just a side remark: `E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED` is **not** the correct way to combine the error reporting levels. Using the current values of the error reporting constants **it happens** that `^` produces the correct value but it's just a coincidence. As a general rule, to express "all but deprecated" you should use `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED`.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the value of variable $valor into a new variable $valor2 before using it on the sql query, and then use that copy ($valor2) for the second echo section.

Comment: I already tried, it didn't work. I also worked with $_SESSION, but again, the second one still empty